# Reference for scientific writing for an international journal in the micro-biology/micro-organism field

Tags: publications, journals

Could someone do me a favor for any guidance (link) for writing an article that is supposed to be submitted to an international journal in micro-biology/micro-organism field?

Could you please lead me to another source instead of [this site](http://abacus.bates.edu/~ganderso/biology/resources/writing/HTWgeneral.html)?

Comment: Hi des, and welcome to Academia Stack Exchange! We already have some good resources for writing papers: *[How to write an academic paper for the first time?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11989/how-to-write-an-academic-paper-for-the-first-time)* Are you asking about advice specific to micro-biology/micro-organism?