# Writing a research paper

Tags: research-process

I am a 16 years old high school student. I want to publish a new piece of work. Writing a research paper is quite difficult for me. If some body has any idea about how to do that then help me.

Comment: What do you mean of `a new piece of work`?! You mean an invention or something?

Comment: What is it going to be about?

Comment: @henning It is about mathematics.

Comment: I am upvoting this only for the reason that research & publishing, especially in STEM fields, should be encouraged amongst the younger generation. I understand that this is a bit of an anomaly question, since writing a paper requires formal training, but we should still be encouraging.

Comment: @AlexandersWilliam: Research paper is not actually defined within the scope of the high school pupils... You might confirm that any idea needs to be cooked, efficiently, before publication. So the `younger generation` should wait for entrance to the university, firstly!!

Comment: @matinking Perhaps. I elaborated a bit more in my answer below as to what the student can do, that will be appropriate for his level.

Comment: Publishing a new piece of work is easy: there are plenty of predatory publishers that will publish your work for a small fee. Perhaps instead it is worth aspiring to get involved in *great research*.

Comment: See: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11989/how-to-write-an-academic-paper-for-the-first-time (I assume your question is strictly about writing, not about research.)

Comment: I would like to mention that writing papers is difficult for scientists too. Usually, it takes several months of (full time work) to finish one.

Comment: @matinking Additionally, I disagree fully at your above comment to me. If you look at the Intel/Google/Simons Science Fairs, The MIT PRIMES and RSI programs, the Emory University Summer Scholars Programs , and numerous other programs, these programs promote research amongst high school students (and sometimes younger), culminating in a professional research paper. Although it may not go in a major journal, it is still a research paper.

Comment: @matinking I disagree with your statement, and while you have to right to state what you wish, I would kindly ask that you encourage our younger generation to seek out opportunities to engage in STEM fields, and such programs. We should identify talent, and help breed new talent. Even if the OP's research paper turns out to be mediocre or so, we should encourage the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am glad to know that you are interested in publishing a new piece of work in the field of mathematics. Here is what I would suggest: Look at institutions such as MIT RSI and PRIMES, as well as the Simons/Google/Intel science fairs, and also opportunities in your locality. Look at examples of mathematics reports submitted to them, and then copy that format and write your paper. It may be difficult to submit to an actual journal though for publishing. Academia is a bit brutal, and so it is better to work through the institutions that I mentioned. If your work is actually a breakthrough, then you will still be recognized, and these are good opportunities for students like you.

If not, I would suggest emailing or getting in contact with a mathematics professor (possibly at your local university, and one who focuses in that area of mathematics), and talk to him. Ask him if he would be willing to look over it and send him what you have.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you go through the guidelines of writing an effective paper. Such material are scattered throughout the Internet.

A (very) brief set of general steps to write a research paper:

1. **Ground Work**: Do a literature survey of work done related to the work you wish to publish.
2. **Assess Scope**: Answer questions like where could your method be applied? Who would find it useful? Is it better than what is done traditionally? Could it improve the community in the field of your work?
3. **Experiment**: Apply your method in action. In mathematics, you might have to show the theoretical worth through series of derivations.
4. **Analyse**: answer questions like how effective is this method as you claim it to be in comparison to the the ones in the related work? What are its advantages and drawbacks? Can you visualise your results in any form?
5. **Compile**: when you feel you did enough of the above, you could put you work together to form an article manuscript you could submit for publication.